# Mysql optimizing query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have some existing Mysql query and just wondering how to IMPROVE it. Because it's take sometimes up to 20s to execute.
Well in fact it's take up to 0.3690s to find right records but then when need to get 40k record is take up to 20s .

So my question is how can I improve my settings or my sql code to get records faster? Or it's depend now only on my machine (such SAS hard drive) ?

First some necessary info: 
my application use MySQL server 5.6 and InnoDB Engine
my custom settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 7G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
join_buffer_size = 32M
tmp_table_size = 128M
max_heap_table_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
table_open_cache = 4000
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 256M
```

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblusers` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`user_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
`machine_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`lang_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '14',
`user_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
`created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
`active_open` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`email_hash` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`profile_approved` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`menage_data` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`mailing_agree` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`edited` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`warnings` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `user_name_UNIQUEE` (`user_name`),
KEY `fk_tblUsers_hlpLangs1_idx` (`lang_id`),
KEY `email_hash` (`email_hash`),
KEY `trio` (`user_type`,`profile_approved`,`deleted`,`email_hash`),
CONSTRAINT `tblusers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lang_id`) REFERENCES `hlplangs` (`lang_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblhostess` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `sure_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `dob` datetime NOT NULL,
  `driver_license` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sanepid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `province_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `picture_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `hair_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `hair_color_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `number_of_view` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `who_can_see` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `complete_register` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `skin_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `bra_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `wear_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `shoe_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `desc` text,
  `height` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bust` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `waist` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hip` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `redirect_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friend_url` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `premium` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `premium_until` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `work_as_model` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `work_as_hostess` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `work_as_fotomodel` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `work_in_club` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `work_in_party` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `work_in_promo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `work_in_trade` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `work_in_event` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `work_in_gala` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `phone_ver` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cert` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fb_premium` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblHostess_tblCities1_idx` (`city_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblHostess_hlpProvinces1_idx` (`province_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblHostess_hlpHairColor1_idx` (`hair_color_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblHostess_hlpHair1_idx` (`hair_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblHostess_hlpShoes1_idx` (`shoe_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblHostess_hlpBra1_idx` (`bra_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblHostess_hlpWear1_idx` (`wear_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblHostess_hlpSkinColor1_idx` (`skin_id`),
  KEY `premium` (`premium`),
  KEY `num_of_views` (`number_of_view`),
  KEY `views_premium` (`number_of_view`,`premium`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblhostess_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tblusers` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `tblhostess_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `hlpcities` (`city_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `tblhostess_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`province_id`) REFERENCES `hlpprovinces` (`province_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblhostessmailings` (
  `hostess_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new_job_offers` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2' ,
  `comments` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `job_offer_accept` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `private_message` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `job_offer_sms` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `job_offer_private` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hostess_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tblhostessmailings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hostess_id`) REFERENCES `tblhostess` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbljoboffers` (
  `offer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `content_html` text,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `approved` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `edited` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `freqence_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `premium` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL ,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL ,
  `premium_old_user` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sending` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `external_sent` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `internal_sent` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `archiwal` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friend_url` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_export` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `exported` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sms_sent` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sms_sending` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `private` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `private_paid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`offer_id`,`freqence_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblJoboffers_tblEmployers1_idx` (`employer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbljobofferslocations` (
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `offer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `province_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_times` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `offer_id` (`offer_id`,`city_id`,`province_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblJobOffersLocations_hlpProvinces1_idx` (`province_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblJobOffersLocations_tblCities1_idx` (`city_id`),
  KEY `fk_tblJobOffersLocations_tblJobOffers1_idx` (`offer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tbljobofferslocations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`) REFERENCES `tbljoboffers` (`offer_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `tbljobofferslocations_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `hlpcities` (`city_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `tbljobofferslocations_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`province_id`) REFERENCES `hlpprovinces` (`province_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

records count approx in db 
users 100k
job offers around 20k (all)
and locations around 40k

And finally my sql example:

```
select email, first_name, sure_name
            from tblusers u join tblhostess h on h.user_id = u.user_id 
            join tblhostessmailings m on m.hostess_id = h.user_id
            join 
            (select province_id from tbljoboffers o join tbljobofferslocations l on l.offer_id = o.offer_id
            where o.deleted = 0 and o.start_date > date_add(current_timestamp, INTERVAL -1 DAY) and o.approved = 1 and o.active = 1 and o.internal_sent = 1 and o.private = 0
             group by l.province_id) z on z.province_id = h.province_id
            where u.deleted = 0 and u.email_hash = '1' and email != '' and user_type = 1 and (m.new_job_offers = 2)
```

What I wonna to get from here is a list of all users within 1 day who gets at least one offer on their inside mail box 
All jobs are divided into province so this

```
(select province_id from tbljoboffers o join tbljobofferslocations l on l.offer_id = o.offer_id
            where o.deleted = 0 and o.start_date > date_add(current_timestamp, INTERVAL -1 DAY) and o.approved = 1 and o.active = 1 and o.internal_sent = 1 and o.private = 0
             group by l.province_id)
```

gets the full list of region and rest get information about users
Sometimes happens i will need retrive 40k records with this query so I really need to improve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the subquery you are joining by itself.

```
select province_id from tbljoboffers o join tbljobofferslocations l on l.offer_id = o.offer_id
        where o.deleted = 0 and o.start_date > date_add(current_timestamp, INTERVAL -1 DAY) and o.approved = 1 and o.active = 1 and o.internal_sent = 1 and o.private = 0
         group by l.province_id
```

The date comparison in the WHERE clause is likely part of the slow down, how long does that subquery take to run on its own?  A greater than comparison on a date_add function will likely be slow.  But, without changing the query itself you might gain some performance by simply making that subquery into a view and then you can join the view back to the main query.

```
CREATE VIEW vprovince_ids AS
select province_id from tbljoboffers o join tbljobofferslocations l on l.offer_id = o.offer_id
            where o.deleted = 0 and o.start_date > date_add(current_timestamp, INTERVAL -1 DAY) and o.approved = 1 and o.active = 1 and o.internal_sent = 1 and o.private = 0
             group by l.province_id
```

Then your main query would become:

```
select email, first_name, sure_name
            from tblusers u join tblhostess h on h.user_id = u.user_id 
            join tblhostessmailings m on m.hostess_id = h.user_id
            join vprovince_ids z on z.province_id = h.province_id
            where u.deleted = 0 and u.email_hash = '1' and email != '' and user_type = 1 and (m.new_job_offers = 2)
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, well this sub-query is pretty fast actually , it's take around 0.0839 s to complete. So in this case I don't think creating View will change performance of all query. But will try :)

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly restructured the query for readability and to follow the explanation of how I would think / apply indexes to the respective tables.

```
select 
      u.email, 
      u.first_name, 
      u.sure_name
   from 
      tblusers u 
         join tblhostess h 
            on u.user_id = h.user_id
            join tblhostessmailings m 
               on h.user_id = m.hostess_id
              and m.new_job_offers = 2
            join (
            select DISTINCT
                  l.province_id 
               from 
                  tbljoboffers o 
                     join tbljobofferslocations l 
                        on o.offer_id = l.offer_id
               where 
                      o.deleted = 0 
                  and o.approved = 1 
                  and o.active = 1 
                  and o.internal_sent = 1 
                  and o.private = 0
                  and o.start_date > date_add( current_timestamp, INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
                 ) z 
                  on h.province_id = z.province_id
   where 
          u.deleted = 0 
      and u.email_hash = '1' 
      and u.user_type = 1 
      and u.email != ''
```

First, your queries would be best to have all columns represent the proper table (or alias) they are coming from so others in the future, or offering help don't have to guess where columns are coming from which tables (yet you did provide the table structures).

To better handle your queries, having your table with a bunch of individual indexes is not the best way to support your queries.  Instead, you need to have indexes that match the type of criteria you are searching on.  In  the case of the inner query of job offers, you are explicitly looking for 6 criteria, AND applying a group by.  Having an index on the criteria components will significantly improve.  Also, due to the other criteria, I have moved the date basis to the end, both visually, and as part of the index.  Since you are not doing any aggregates by province, I removed the group by, and just did DISTINCT.

```
table          create index on...
tblJobOffers   ( deleted, approved, active, internal_sent, private, start_date )
```

Think of the indexes like this.  If you had individual indexes on things like deleted or approved or active...  Only one of them would be used as basis to help optimize the query.  But since multiple fields are used in your query, it would be faster to use those indexes that matched multiple criteria you are running with.

Try to think of it like this... Each index is a box with the content ordered first by the first field, then sub-sorted by the field under it and so forth.

If you index on just "deleted", you have two boxes... one with all deleted stuff, one with NOT deleted.  Similar if only an "active" index.  But by having a composite index as I have, the engine can jump quickly to the records in question...  Seeing your column names, they appear to be "flags" of either on = 1, or off = 0

```
Deleted = 0
   Approved = 0
      (ignored, you don't want approved = 0)
   Approved = 1
      Active = 0
         (ignored, you don't want active = 0)
      Active = 1
         Internal_Sent = 0
            (ignored, you don't want internal sent = 0)
         Internal_Sent = 1
            Private = 0
               Start_Date
                   2014 Dec...
                   2015 Jan...
                   2015 Feb...
                   2015 Feb 4
                   2015 Feb 5
                   2015 Feb 6
            Private = 1
               (ignored, you don't want private = 1)

Deleted = 1
   (ignored since you are not even looking for deleted = 1 records)
```

So, following the tree down, the index can jump directly to the 2015 Feb transactions,  get those and ignore everything else.  Use that to join to the province locations and it's done.

For your OUTER query, your join TO the **"tblhostessmailings"** is based on the hostess ID, but also you are only looking for specific flag of new job offers = 2.  Have that as a compound index too.  Hostess table is joined by the user ID, so that should have an index.  And tblUsers has multiple criteria too, so that (in similar context as job offers above) should have a compound index

```
table                index
tblhostessmailings   ( hostess_id, new_job_offers )
tblhostess           ( user_id )
tblusers             ( deleted, user_type, email_hash, email )
```

See what these sugggestions and revised query do for your performance, and let us know the performance improvement as a result, good or bad.

Answer (score -1):

- Indexed columns on performing the search, not on selecting
- Use unique indexes
- Use short indices
- Do not abuse indexes

Comment: Well, you are of course right, but this is just a guidelines . My question was more about what can do to make it more efficient in case mentioned above.